# Add Permalink to Post Thumbnail, syntax code issues

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails, code

I´d like to link `the_post_thumbnail` by using the  `the_permalink`.

I do this (**It  Works without link**)

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'xyz', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

   the_post_thumbnail('wine-flow', array('class' => 'item'));

endwhile; ?>
```

And I´d like to do further this: (**Syntax Error**)

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'xyz', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
   <?php the_post_thumbnail('wine-flow', array('class' => 'item')); ?>
   </a>

endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks
ogni

Comment: You are mixing html and php code without "escaping" the html code with the php tags: <?php & ?>. Is it only the syntax you have a problem with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you haven't close php before anchor tag

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'xyz', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
   <?php the_post_thumbnail('wine-flow', array('class' => 'item')); ?>
   </a>
<?php
endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to jump out of PHP after calling `$loop->the_post()`, because you are writing HTML after that. You also need to jump back into PHP before `endwhile;` because that is PHP and not HTML.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'xyz', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
   <?php the_post_thumbnail('wine-flow', array('class' => 'item')); ?>
   </a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```